# Changing date format in a DatePicker in MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, datepicker

I've seen various threads all over the web about this, but nothing seems to work for me.

**Problem**

In my MVC aplpication, I have an `Html.TextBoxFor` which is fed with a property from my model. Such property could be the following: `public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }`. A simple and basic `DateTime` property.

The razer input looks like this:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Expiration, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

I'm initializing the datepicker like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(fucntion(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' });
    });
</script>
```

According to the many sources I've read, this setup should work, but in my application it's not. In the picture below you can clearly see how I've picked (*in format `dd/MM/yyyy`*) the 9th of May, or rather `09/05/2016`, but as you can also see, the text input in the text box is `05/09/2016`, so the 5th of September as the date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

[image]

**Extra**

I've tried using the `Html.EditorFor` with the following template:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

AND

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

But still nothing works. I've tried simply defining the format in the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` directly, like so: `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Expiration, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })` but this makes no difference either.

Comment: _In the picture below_? - you have not included an image :)

Comment: There we go.. Thank you for noticing :)

Comment: Which jquery plugin are you using? (and best guess is it needs to be `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'` - lower case `mm`)

Comment: `jquery-2.1.4` and `jquery-ui-1.10.4`. I've tried using the small `mm`, as the big ones are C#, but to no avail

Comment: If its jquery ui datepicker, then it needs to be lower case `dd/mm/yyyy` for a 2 digit month

Comment: Still no difference @StephenMuecke. The date I'm handling is `09/05/2016` in format `mm/dd/yyyy` so tjhe datepicker reverts this and thinks that the month is `05` though that's the date.

Comment: Works fine for me and displays the correct date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115207/discussion-between-detilium-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the day (number - two digit)/month (number - two digit)/ year (four digit) use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
```

For a full list of formatting options check [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) out.

In your specific example it looks like a combination of `/` instead of `-` and upper case letters instead of lower case are causing your issue.